# Search for enum inside array of enums in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

Can i have an array of enums and search for a specific enum, or just check if it exists, inside that array in C++11?

Comment: Do you mean s.th. like `std::set<YourEnum>` or some static checks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
if (std::find(begin(array), end(array), expectedValue) != end(array)) {
    // Found the expected enum value
}
```

Comment: Can it return the found value?

Comment: It should be `!= end(array)`

Comment: Is it efficient? Or should i use something else for this?

Comment: Premature optimisation is the root of all evil ;)

Comment: @vinnylinux You mean does it return `expectedValue`, or a `bool`? No.

Comment: Why would it need to, if it succeeded in finding expectedValue, you already know what expectedValue is!

Comment: @DaveS: Whoops, fixed that.
@vinnylinux: You pretty much aren't getting more efficient than this, assuming `array` is a linear array.

Comment: `std::find` returns an iterator pointing to the found value, or the end iterator if none was found. It would be easy to modify this answer to get the found value. But then, you already know the value you're looking for. Maybe the array index would be more useful, which could be found using `std::distance`.